# are there Different permissions with touch.facebook.com and www.facebook.com?

Tags: iphone, android, facebook, mobile, touch

have a facebook page that has public info that can be accessed without logging in.
However, when I access it through touch.facebook.com, it demands a login.

The page is : http://www.facebook.com/soho.sushi.bar
and the touch : http://touch.facebook.com/soho.sushi.bar

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - touch.facebook.com requires login. m.facebook.com however, leaves public info public.